# Calculating elapsed time

Tags: c, vb.net

```
main()
{
    clock_t start, end;
    double elapsed;

    start = clock();

     /* some function */

    end = clock();

    elapsed = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

I have no knowledge of VB.NET, and I need the preceding C program in VB.NET. I'd also like the elapsed time to show the number of days when the elapsed time exceeds 24 hours.

Comment: Stackoverflow is no code gen machine.

Comment: @juergend It seems that it is, though.

Comment: Please see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) for some guidance on SO so that you can use it in a, *to you*, helpful way which will indirectly also benefit the SO community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the [`System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class to time operations precisely in .NET.

```vb
Dim stopwatch As New Stopwatch()

stopwatch.Start()

'Perform timed operations here

stopwatch.Stop()
```

The elapsed `TimeSpan` may now be retrieved as `stopwatch.Elapsed`. For a direct analogue to your C code, you would write:

```vb
Dim elapsed = stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
```

Comment: thank you, would you please be more specific as i have no idea of stopwatch class.

Comment: @SharatMalaler: I inferred by your question that you had no idea what the `Stopwatch` class was; however, I have provided a complete example and included a link to the documentation of `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class, which should be sufficient if you read it through thoroughly. If you require further assistance after doing so, please be more specific about what part exactly it is that you don't understand.